solana pirate bootcamp quest 5 - "Access violation in unknown section at address 0x225191a2c759e156 of size 2080669590007288142
While trying the Solana Bootcamp Episode 5 arbitrage bot on devnet and learning Rust (code found here: https://github.com/solana-developers/pirate-bootcamp/tree/main/quest-5) I have been experiencing access violation errors such as
Program logged: "Swap #1 Pool: 7BURVAbScooj2KzYPBx5Pw4ruJSJcxWZTTMBdz7Qmxtv"        
Program logged: "Swap #2 Pool: 9SbiegVbHjKwWHYcJckSkex3CDRBqsEV3gZLX5WKHMe1"        
Program logged: "PLACING TRADE!"        
Program logged: "Buy on Swap #1 and sell on Swap #2"        
Program logged: "Executing buy ..."       
Program consumed: 155478 of 200000 compute units        
Program returned error: "Access violation in unknown section at address 0x225191a2c759e156 of size 2080669590007288142"

The code is identical to the one run in the boot camp, which seems to have run for the author last year (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XiA_pBftFt4&t=890s). However, despite trying Solana versions 1.14, 1.16, and 1.18, I continue to get access violations.
I have seen some suggestions of using the box method when experiencing this type of error, I have tried this to no avail, while still unsure how the author had the code running in July 2023 as part of the boot camp as-is without any need for boxing.
When running the arb bot all transactions seem to fail: https://explorer.solana.com/address/9KgMzdMUTR6kHWvu1HdeA4Zu81i724dxjJnTmTUFEEwx?cluster=devnet
Has anyone experienced this before or can suggest some ideas for debugging? Initially I thought it might be related to an issue with Bytemuck not deserialising mint_athority metadata correctly in the PartialMintState function, deserialising the wrong part of the data due to incorrect slicing not taking into account initial "1 0 0 0" in mint account raw data (decimals seem to be at point 45 not at point 41), but now I am not too sure as no error is being thrown, code for tis part below:
pub type ArbitrageMintInfo<'a, 'b> = (&'a AccountInfo<'b>, u8);

impl PartialMintState {        `
    /// Attempts to use zero-copy deserialization via Bytemuck to determine if    
    /// this account is in fact a mint account
    ///
    /// If it is, it will return only the vital information we need
    /// for the rest of the arbitrage program
    pub fn try_deserialize<'a, 'b>(
        account_info: &'a AccountInfo<'b>,
    ) -> Result<ArbitrageMintInfo<'a, 'b>, ProgramError> {
        // Check that the account has enough data to try to deserialize
        if account_info.data_len() < 41 {
            msg!(
                "Data too small. Should be 41. Found len: {}",
                account_info.data_len()
            );
            msg!("Mint: {}", account_info.key);
            return Err(ArbitrageProgramError::InvalidAccountsList.into());
        }
        let data = &account_info.data.borrow()[..41];
        // Try to partially deserialize the account data
        match bytemuck::try_from_bytes::<Self>(&data[..40]) {
            Ok(_) => {
                let decimals = match data.get(40) {
                    Some(d) => d,
                    None => {
                        msg!("Could not get decimals");
                        msg!("Mint: {}", account_info.key);
                        return Err(ArbitrageProgramError::InvalidAccountsList.into());
                    }
                };
                // Return the vital information
                Ok((account_info, *decimals))
            }
            Err(_) => {
                msg!("Failed to deserialize mint account");
                msg!("Mint: {}", account_info.key);
                Err(ArbitrageProgramError::InvalidAccountsList.into())
            }
        }
    }
}

cargo version 1.74.1
solana cli versions tried 1.14, 1.16, 1.18
